# how to update the mouse clicked region in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, window

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

```
    x=LOWORD(lParam);
    y=HIWORD(lParam);
    TextOut(hdc,x,y,"Hello",5);
    break;
```

This code displays the text,"hello" on the client area. But on resizing the window it gets erased. What should I do to get the new position for the mouse event on resizing the window, so that it is not erased on resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Set x and y in WM_LBUTTONDOWN. But instead of calling TextOut call InvalidateRect. That will cause WM_PAINT to come in. Do all your painting in WM_PAINT. You will also get WM_PAINT after a resize. And after some other window uncovers yours. And after minimizing/maximizing. Those are a few of the reasons to do all your painting in WM_PAINT.